# Simple BootStrap not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a very simple Bootstrap example to function and it does not render the span(s) properly.  I do not see the span content render as columns no matter the page size.  Under debug I see the css and related jquery (v 1.9) and bootstrap (v 3.0) scripts  pulled in.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
     <title></title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

     <link href="Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    </head> <body>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="span4">
                 <h2>Column one</h2>
                 <p>
                     Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
 nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem
 malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="span4">
                 <h2>Column one</h2>
                 <p>
                     Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
 nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem
 malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="span4">
                 <h2>Column one</h2>
                 <p>
                     Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
 nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem
 malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
                 </p>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: didn't understand your problem...:( could you please more elaborate it.

Comment: Whats the question? What is not working? Btw: in HTML5 you don't close single tags with `... />`

Comment: The question is given that I have such a simple html page, why does it not render the span(s) as columns???

Comment: I tried to include code but as its html its rendering the output instead of showing as a code snippet. I have edited the question to show html

Comment: You're using v2 markup

Answer (score 1):

did u put the script file in the Scripts folder ?
look at your navigator source code and make sure by clicking on

```
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

that the script is accessible

Answer (score 0):

V2 markup was in fact the issue. Removed span replaced with col4-md